# Clojure: Agent calling Agent: suspicion of deadlock?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, deadlock, agent

Consider the following code:

```
(let 
  [slave-agent (agent 0)
   run-slave (fn [_] (println "running slave agent"))
   run-master (fn [_]
            (loop []
              (println "sending to slave agent")
              (send-off slave-agent run-slave)
              (Thread/sleep 1000)
              (recur)
              )
            )
   master-agent (agent nil)
   ]
   (send-off master-agent run-master)  
  )
```

Using any combination of send/send-off, I could not have the slave-agent running.
However when I run run-master in a classical java.lang.Thread, everything works fine.

Has anyone an idea.

Thank you

Regards

J-C

Answer (score 2):

`send` in a agent action (or transaction) are held till the action (or transaction) completted (and committed). However your run-master never returns. So you just accumulate `send-off` requests which are actually never submitted for execution. Try something like this:

```
(defn run-master
  [_]
  (send-off slave-agent run-slave)
  (send-off *agent* run-master)
  (Thread/sleep 1000))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The worker pool used by send-off is unbounded. So the example code in the question will be working fine because only the one thread (running run-master action) will hold the thread from `send-off` thread-pool. Every time when we use `send-off` function we know that action execution can block and that isn't incorrect or unexpected behavior.

Comment: So I understand that the explanation of Kotarak is correct? After reading the documentation, I simply did not understand the expected behavior of send/send-off.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @hsestupin The point is that the `send` does not happen immediately in an agent action. It is delayed until the action completes. When that never happens... then the send never happens.

Comment: @jcmincke See bullet point 5 in the [agent docs](http://clojure.org/agents). This is exactly the "problem" you are running into.

Comment: @kotarak sry, you are right! Didn't know about that point 5 in the agent docs. It clarifies a lot for me.